# Import excel data both text and image into mysql php

Tags: php, excel

I want to upload an excel sheet of xls or xlsx format which contain both text and image..(One image for each row).How can i upload data into mysql table and image into folder with row id.

Comment: can you please elaborate you question a bit more? You will need some php excel lib for it, but without info cannot really help

Comment: Yes i used phpExcel to extract image from excel to a folder..its working fine...but i want store row data into mysql table and also save the image with name as row id.